# multiple imputation with binary variables

Tags: r, missing-data, binary-data, multiple-imputation

I have 54 missing values in my dataset of 459 cases. Variables are all binary (0-1). I want to try a multiple imputation to avoid a listwise deletion, using the `mi` package for R. However, I ran a first analysis and the message was `mi did not converge`. I simply used the command:

```
mi(mydata)
```

leaving the default 30 iterations and 3 imputations.

**Question: what are the best practices to do a multiple imputation for binary variables using the `mi` package?**

Comment: I've never used this package. One troubleshooting approach is to make a temp data set with same structure and fill in all but one value; run mi ; does it do what you expect?

Comment: I do not think I fully understand your approach. BTW, in the `Amelia` package this is easy: there is an `ords` option that sets one or more variable as ordered categorical. It seems that `mi` package treats these variables in a different manner.